# jQuery IE7 and IE8 security information popup

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

Upon deploying our application from staging to production, users on IE7 and IE8 are reporting seeing the following popup:

[image]

Thinking it was a resource used in the application, we stripped down the page to just this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#content').html("Here is where the popup happens.");
    });
</script>

<div id="content">
</div>
```

Needless to say our users are not thrilled to see a security message popup and asking all of our users to disable this message in their browser is not solution.

What is causing this and how can it be resolved?

Comment: Is this on an HTTPS page?

Comment: its because your page is on https and you are requesting a item that is from a http, simply use https for you google url `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js`

Comment: @DavidThomas - yes, it is HTTPS that is causing the issue.

Comment: @PatrickEvans - oh so omitting the protocol makes it use HTTPS instead of HTTP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

to

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

The browser will fill in the protocol based on the page's protocol.